# How to show html files with modal.open using jquery?

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-selectors

Currently i use a fine working code for opening a modal with Jquery :

```
            $(document).ready(function(){          
            $("span.ico-detail").click(function(){
                modal.open({content: "View detail of " + $(this).parent().parent().attr("id")});
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
```

And now the problem is : How can I use **modal.open** to open a HTML file named "view.html", which contaning the string of "*View detail of* "?

What should I change the **content : "xxx"** with, so I can open the HTML file (view.html) and join it with other text ?

Thanks before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `view.html` is stored on a server and its content is static, then you can choose to preload the content of the file using ajax.

```
$(function () {
    window.myAppNs = {
        viewContent: null;
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: 'view.html',
        dataType: 'html',
        type: 'GET'
    }).done(function (resp) {
        myAppNs.viewContent = resp;
    });

    $("span.ico-detail").click(function(){
        modal.open({content: myAppNs.viewContent + $(this).parent().parent().attr("id")});
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I am creating a global variable `myAppNs`. This will hold all app related variables. The idea is not pollute the global namespace with unnecessary variables. There are better and safer ways to create a namespace. If that interests you, you can google for the same.

The ajax call preloads the content of the `view.html` and stores it in `myAppNs.viewContent`. The click handler reads that content from the variable.

There is a slight chance that the user can click the element before the ajax response is returned. If that's an issue, you can always move the namespace creation and ajax call out of `document.ready` and place it in the `head` section, immediately after referencing `jquery`. That ought to give the browser enough time to fetch the content before the dom is ready, but there is still that small possibility that the response might be delayed. If you need to ensure the user can click only if the data has been fetched, then bind the click handler inside the `done` callback of the ajax call.

Comment: Great it works... but Can I replace the " url: 'view.html', dataType: 'html' " with "view.php?code=a001" ? so I can use the dynamic PHP with mysql ?

Comment: Sure. As long as the response of `view.php` has the correct mimetype set, you can exclude the `dataType` option. Else, you will want to include the `dataType` option. You can find more information in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ ... That should be a good start. If you have more queries, you can search for the same on SO or create a new question.

Comment: The code as it stands will request the content of `view.php?code=a001` only once. If the response can possibly vary with time or other parameters, you will need to move the ajax call to a more appropriate location.